# Android: Webview does not resize on rotation (ICS)

Tags: android, android-webview, screen-rotation

I have a simple WebView in my layout, with the following setup

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/baserepeat"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >
 <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/productDetailContentWebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/baserepeat" />
//other items...
```

Inside my manifest I have the containing activity set to

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Products.ProductDetailActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CPS" >
    </activity>
```

My Webview is populated with a simple HTML file on the device, which works nicely. The problem is that when I rotate the device from portrait to landscale, the webview becomes a good deal taller, pushing whatever was below it further down in my layout. The amount of content doesn't change - it is all set in OnCreate().

I'm using the Webview to render the content with it's own special stylesheet, and it must stay within the ScrollView.

I can provide more information if required :)

Comment: try removing `screenSize` from `screenSize` in Manifest

Comment: Gamma this is the correct answer, please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar issue when working on 2.3/4.0...

I tried several things but the solution which helped me in getting rid of the core issue was:

*removing `screenSize` from `android:configChanges` in `AndroidManifest.xml`*

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Didn't think it would work; tried anyway; freaking works!! Now my manifest only has `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try including your webview inside a FrameLayout.

```
<LinearLayout>
   <FrameLayout>  
   <WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/productDetailContentWebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/baserepeat" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: No luck on that front, the behavior remains the same

Comment: Can you add the webview programmatically in the code? Say have the FrameLayout in your layout xml and try adding the webview programmatically.

Comment: This worked in conjunction with GAMA's answer but unfortunately not without it. Thankyou for your help cutebug!